# presto-cli processing the real data type column value to 6 digits after decimal

Tags: coordinates, presto

I have a column with data type as "real" in Presto. Ex: Latitude with value -84.55158233642578. I am using "presto-cli" to fetch the data from database. Value I see now is -84.551582 (Sometimes 5 digits after decimal). I need the full precision. Please let me know if there is a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

`real` is 32-bit floating point number, so i[t has about 7 decimal digits of precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format). CLI shows you the most precise value it can have. To have higher precision, you should use `double` data type.

Comment: Maybe use a the driver like (e.g., JDBC, ODBC, Python, R, etc), and get the actual value instead of trying to parse from the CLI text.

Comment: Also if the value is processed as `real` (32-bit floating point) and only later cast to double, you won't have more precision. At most, you can have more digits being displayed. To actually have more precision, you need to process your data as `double` at all stages.